# How to use pgp.as.format for a transaction

Tags: postgresql, pg-promise

Is it possible to use `pgp.as.format` to see raw postgres queries generated by a transaction `db.tx(t => ...)`? I can't figure out the syntax for this use-case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can't figure out what query is generated, you have the following options:

- Start using [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor) that will show you all the queries automatically
- Manually connect to event [query](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/global.html#event:query)
- Use function [as.format](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/formatting.html#.format)

> Is it possible to use `pgp.as.format`

Why wouldn't it be possible? The function is there to be used independently whenever needed. But in your case, for viewing generated queries, the other two options are better.